# Running a script on autostart using rc.local

Tags: pi-2

> Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

I would like to run a script on start-up with my Raspberry Pi. I've followed some guides and the easiest method seems to be editing the `rc.local` file, which is what I did. So I opened up the `rc.local` file using:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Then, before the `exit 0` line, on separate lines I added

```
cd RPi_Cam_Web_Interface  //just my 2 commands
./start.sh
```

Saved the file using Ctrl+O, and rebooted. However my script doesn't run. I checked the file and my new commands are there. What could be wrong here?

Comment: is your folder in root / ? rc.local executes in root so if your folder is not in root you need to include the full path whrn you change directory i.e cd /home/RPi_Cam....

Comment: You still do not get an acceptable answer. You should really use a systemd Unit file now, to start your script. Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

As paj (almost?) points out, at least one problem is your `cd` command using a relative path when it should use an absolute path. If I remember correctly, rc.local is run as root, and the current working directory won't be your pi user home directory or whatever user you use. Using `cd /home/pi/RPi_Cam_Web_Interface` should solve your problem.

The next problem might be running your script without &, depending on what your script does. If you use it to start a long-running process, but don't run them in the background then the script and thus rc.local will wait for such programs to complete, before continuing. This is probably not what you want. `start.sh &` is probably what you want to do here.

Answer (score 0):

In rc.local, use:

--- snip ---

`sudo -u cameraUser /path/to/camera/dataDir/start.sh &
echo $! > /var/run/camera.pid`

--- snip ---

This is very vanilla. Add a `trap` at the beginning of start.sh to handle various signals. E.g. `trap "ohno, caught INT, cleaning up and dying! ; doThis ; doThat ; rm /var/run/camera.pid" INT`. If necessary, clear the trap with `trap - INT`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try these two commands in Terminal. If they are working fine, they will work in `rc.local`. If the process is continuous or a long process, then add `&` at the end of your command. It will work. Also do check the permissions for `start.sh`. If there is no permission for user `pi`, change the permissions using `chmod`.